# Databinding is not working between two tabbedpage children

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin.Forms development and I'm trying to build a tiny Xamarin app to start. 
My app currently has one main TabbedPage that has two ContentPages children. On the ListePage, I have a ListView with an ObservableCollection with OlonaModel is an object with an int Numero and a Text string. I would like the Details page to show details of the selected OlonaModel from the listview of ListePage, but the Details page doesn't seem to update to changes when I select an item from the listview.
Both of the content pages are bound to the same ListPageViewModel. The view model updates when I select an item from the listview, but the changes aren't reflected on the Details page and I'm really confused.
How can I make the Details refresh itself when the SelectedItem of the view model gets set ?

The MainPage :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App.Views"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:App.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App.MainPage">
    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <local:ListePage/>
        <local:Details/>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

The ListePage.xaml (ContentPage1 in the post) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App.Views.ListePage"
             Title="Liste">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="ListeMipoitra" ItemSelected="ListeMipoitra_ItemSelected">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Numero}" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The ListePage.xaml.cs :

```
namespace App.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ListePage : ContentPage
    {
        public static ListePageViewModel viewModel;
        public ListePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            viewModel = new ListePageViewModel();
            this.BindingContext = viewModel;
            ListeMipoitra.ItemsSource = viewModel.listeOlonaVM;
        }

        private void ListeMipoitra_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            viewModel.setSelected((OlonaModel)e.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
}
```

The Details.xaml (ContentPage2 in the post) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App.Views.Details"
             Title="Détails">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The Details.xaml.cs :

```
namespace App.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Details : ContentPage
    {
        public Details()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = ListePage.viewModel.selected;
        }
    }
}
```

The ListePageViewModel.cs :

Note: I'm using Fody and PropertyChanged.Fody weaver, so the RaisePropertyChanged() event (should be) is called automatically when a property changes

```
namespace App.ViewModels
{

    public class ListePageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        public ObservableCollection<OlonaModel> listeOlonaVM;

        public OlonaModel selected { get; set; }

        public ListePageViewModel()
        {
            listeOlonaVM = new ObservableCollection<OlonaModel>();
            listeOlonaVM = ListeOlona.liste;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void setSelected(OlonaModel olona)
        {
            selected = olona;
        }
    }
}
```

The model of the Olona object :

```
namespace App.Models
{
    public class OlonaModel
    {
        public int Numero { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public OlonaModel(int num, string text)
        {
            this.Numero = num;
            this.Text= text;
        }
    }
}
```

The ListeOlona.cs where the model of the list is stored:

The InitializeList() method is called at App Startup.

```
namespace App.ViewModels
{
    public static class ListeOlona 
    {
        public static ObservableCollection<OlonaModel> liste = new ObservableCollection<OlonaModel>();

        public static void InitializeList()
        {
            liste.Add(new OlonaModel(1,
                "FirstItem"));
            liste.Add(new OlonaModel(2,
                "Second Item"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post what you’ve tried

Comment: we can't debug code we can't see

Comment: Sorry, added code to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, there is tabbedpage, two pages, one is Listpage, another is detailpage, you want to select listview item in listpage, then other detail info will display detailpage, am I right?

If yes, I suggest you can do this like this:

**TabbedPage:**

```
<TabbedPage
x:Class="App4.TabbedPage2"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App4"
x:Name="tabbedpage2">
<!--  Pages can be added as references or inline  -->
<TabbedPage.Children>
    <local:ListPage Title="Mian page" BindingContext="{Binding}" />
    <local:DetailPage Title="Detail page" BindingContext="{Binding select}" />
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

```
  public partial class TabbedPage2 : TabbedPage
{
    public TabbedPage2 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new ListePageViewModel();
    }     
}

public class OlonaModel
{
    public int Numero { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class ListePageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<OlonaModel> listeOlonaVM { get; set; }
    private OlonaModel _select;
    public OlonaModel select
    {
        get { return _select; }
        set
        {
            _select = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("select");
        }
    }
    public ListePageViewModel()
    {
        listeOlonaVM = new ObservableCollection<OlonaModel>()
        {
            new OlonaModel(){Numero=1,Text="first item"},
            new OlonaModel(){Numero=2,Text="second item"},
            new OlonaModel(){Numero=3,Text="third item"},
            new OlonaModel(){Numero=4,Text="fouth item"}

        };
        select = listeOlonaVM[0];
    }
}
```

**ListPage:**

```
 <StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding listeOlonaVM}" SelectedItem="{Binding select}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Numero}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

**DetailPage:**

```
  <StackLayout>
        <Label
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Text="{Binding Text}"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
```

**ViewModelBase** implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface.

```
 public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

[image]